# How to implement WPF User Control with UIElement dependency properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties, uielement

I have a user control with this code behind:

```
/// <summary>
/// The text to use for the header.
/// </summary>
public UIElement HeaderText
{
    get { return (UIElement) GetValue(HeaderTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value); }
}

public static DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderText",
                                typeof(UIElement),
                                typeof(Panel),
                                new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(HeaderTextPropertyChanged)));

private static void HeaderTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = d as Panel;
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.HeaderText = (UIElement) e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

And this XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding local:CustomPanel.HeaderText}" />
```

And I'm trying to use the user control like this:

```
<controls:CustomPanel>
    <controls:CustomPanel.HeaderText>
        <TextBlock Text="Foo " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bar}" />
        <TextBlock Text=" baz." />
    </controls:CustomPanel.HeaderText>
</controls:CustomPanel>
```

However, what I get is blank/empty text.

I can get it to work if I change `UIElement` into `string` in code-behind, but **I want to accept both `string`, `TextBlock`** and practically any `UIElement` that makes sense for text.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That property changed callback is mighty useless.

Comment: (Did a rollback because you had pretty much removed everything that made up your original question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `TextBlock` in your control but a `ContentPresenter` (and bind the `Content`), it can host anything. Make the property type `object` and change the name to `Header` for consistency.

(As a side-note: Usually you have additional properties that go along with the `Header`, namely a `HeaderTemplate` and a `HeaderTemplateSelector`. If the `ContentPresenter` is in a template you can make it bind to all three properties by setting the [`ContentSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.contentsource.aspx) to `"Header"`)

Comment: "TextBlock does not match the element ContentPresenter". Is there something special I need to do?

Comment: @rFactor: Not really, just change the declaration XAML to this: `<ContentPresenter Content="..."/>` and change the property type to `object`. How did you get that error? Sounds odd...

Comment: Okay I solved it, there was some extra style that caused the issue. :)

Comment: But what made you say "property changed callback" is useless?

Comment: @rFactor: It does nothing, you don't need to manually change the property, that has happend at the point of the callback already.